# Starting Java application via web start

Tags: java, netbeans, jnlp, java-web-start

I've generated a jnlp file with Netbeans. By double clicking it, I get the following error dialog:

[image]

Double clicking the jar works, so no problem there but when double clicking the jnlp file, the antecedent error appears.

The `launch.jnlp` file looks this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>...</title>
        <vendor>....</vendor>
        <homepage href=""/>
        <description>...</description>
        <description kind="short">....</description>
        <icon href="icon.png" kind="default"/>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <update check="background"/>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+"/>
        <jar href="File.jar" main="true"/>
        <jar href="lib/itextpdf-5.3.3.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="right.path.to.my.main.class.here">
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

I put the `File.jar` in the same directory as the jnlp file (all the others are there too).

Comment: you also have an `<icon href="...">` is that icon also in the same path?

Comment: Yes, the icon is there. Clarified the message.

Comment: Did you click on the Details button on the error message dialog?  What did it say?

Comment: Thanks! I signed the application with Netbeans and added security element in the jnlp file and it worked!

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `codebase` attribute to `jnlp` element, added

```
<security>
    <all-permissions />
</security>
```

and signed the application (right click on the project in Netbeans, select `Properties` and `Application -> Web start` and sign it there) and now it works.